# What is the importance of Handedness?

Tags: character-creation, basic-role-playing

The [Basic Role Playing system](https://www.chaosium.com/content/FreePDFs/BRP/CHA2021%20-%20Basic%20RolePlaying%20Quick-Start.pdf) by Chaosium requires a player to specify their character's handedness:

> **Handedness**: Is the character right- or left-handed? Pick
>   one—there are no game system differences.

There are no other mentions of handedness in the pdf. If "there are no differences", why is it important enough to include it in the character sheet? Can it be just a part of the character's Description, can't it?

Comment: As the link goes to a quick-start guide—therefore by its nature incomplete—would an examination of the importance of handedness to the full game be of interest?

Comment: @HeyICanChan it would, since I am not familiar with the full game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at that page in the pdf, there are no game system effects for *any* of the pieces of Identity data.  They have potential roleplaying effects - both in how you feel in-character and in how others might treat you - but they do nothing numerical.  As for why they exist at all... there's a difference between "no game system differences" and "no differences".

If your issue with it is that you personally think of handedness as trivial... well, there are times and places and people for whom it is not.  Beyond that, the entire Identity section is just flavor.  Sometimes, flavor covers less important things.  It's not like including it harms system simplicity.

Comment: I can explain, why do other pieces of Identity matter. Gender and Description describe how does the character looks. Name comes into play every time you talk about the character. But Handedness... it is kinda like the [Tongue rolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue_rolling) trait — clearly a distinction, but not so important. So why is it there?

Comment: @enkryptor I have edited my answer in an attempt to address your concern.